# Akka - Fault tolerance scenario - test fails

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, actor, akka-actor

I'm simulating in a test the conversation between three actors (A, B, C)

```
A --->  MessageA2B  ---> B --->  MessageB2C ---> C
```

When `MessageB2C` is successfully arrived to C then the acknowledgement is sent back to the origin.

```
C --> MessageB2C_Ack --> B --> MessageA2B_Ack --> A
```

The only peculiarity of this conversation is the message `MessageB2C`.
`MessageB2C` is sent at least every 50 ms until C does not answer with its acknowledgement.

I've implemented this simple conversation with scala testkit framework, but the test fail in a particular situation.

https://github.com/freedev/reactive-akka-testkit

When ActorB retries to send MessageB2C more then once time, then is unable to receive the answers from ActorC. And the reply from ActorC to ActorB goes to deadLetters.

```scala
  test("expectNoMessage-case: actorB retries MessageB2C every 50 milliseconds") {
    val actorA = TestProbe()
    val actorC = TestProbe()
    val actorB = system.actorOf(ActorB.props(Props(classOf[TestRefWrappingActor], actorC)), "step1-case2-primary")

    actorA.send(actorB, MessageA2B())

    actorA.expectNoMessage(100.milliseconds)

    actorC.expectMsg(MessageB2C())

    // Retries form above
    actorC.expectMsg(200.milliseconds, MessageB2C())

    // Never reach this point with 100 ms frequency
    actorC.expectMsg(200.milliseconds, MessageB2C())

    actorA.expectNoMessage(100.milliseconds)

    actorC.reply(MessageB2C_Ack())

    // Never reach this point with MessageB2C 50 ms frequency
    actorA.expectMsg(MessageA2B_Ack())
  }
```

This is the `ActorB` code:

```
class ActorB(actorCProps: Props) extends Actor {
  import ActorB._
  import context.dispatcher

  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  val actorC = context.actorOf(actorCProps)

  def retry(actorRef: ActorRef, message: Any, maxAttempts: Int, attempt: Int): Future[Any] = {
    log.info("ActorB - sent message MessageB2C to ActorC " + actorC)
    val future = Patterns.ask(actorRef, message, 50.millisecond) recover {
      case e: AskTimeoutException =>
        if (attempt <= maxAttempts) retry(actorRef, message, maxAttempts, attempt + 1)
        else None
    }
    future
  }

  def receive = {
    case r:MessageA2B => {
      val client = context.sender()
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(100.milliseconds)
      implicit val scheduler=context.system.scheduler
      val p = MessageB2C()

      retry(actorC, p, 10) onSuccess({
        case p: MessageB2C_Ack => {
          client ! MessageA2B_Ack()
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update

Strangely the test completes successfully commenting the line `actorA.expectNoMessage`

Answer (score 1):

Tests like this can be flakey because they depend on exact timings of execution but actual execution can be affected by various factors including system load (and maybe cosmic rays). That said, I was able to get your test to pass with a couple of modifications to ActorB...

```
 RetrySupport
    .retry(() => {
      log.info("ActorB - sent message MessageB2C to ActorC " + actorC)
      Patterns.ask(actorC, p, 100.millisecond)
    }, 10, 0.millisecond)
    .onSuccess({
      case p: MessageB2C_Ack => {
        log.info(
          "ActorB - Received MessageB2C_Ack so now sending an MessageA2B_Ack to client " + client
        )
        client ! MessageA2B_Ack()
      }
    })
```

The key to debugging the issue was to look at the timings of the log "ActorB - sent message MessageB2C to ActorC Actor". I was seeing times of around 250ms. The problem was the length of time you wait for your `ask` is added to the `delay` parameter of the `retry`. In order to wait 100ms between messages you should set the delay time to 0 and use the ask timeout to manage the retry scheduling.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer does not change my result. In my case `MessageB2C_Ack` was not delivered to ActorB. Dead letters encountered. And this cause a cascade effect `assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for MessageA2B_Ack()`

Comment: I think the solution I found for the test is flaky

Comment: Yeah I think the real solution is to think in terms of why do things go wrong (i.e to dead letters) when the timings are different, and then fix that.

Comment: Someone suggested me that the deadLetters comes because it is raised an Exception that I'm not aware of, and ActorB is terminated. So I've written my own `retry` function and the Patterns.ask really rises a `AskTimeoutException`, but it is caught. Though having caught the exceptions seem not to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around to find an answer, finally found something, well someone.

Long story short, here is the reply I had in the Akka forum:

> Something that might not be obvious about using `Patterns.ask`, is that
>   it spawns a temporary actor that only exists to receive the reply and
>   complete the `Future` returned from `ask`. That temporary actor is used as
>   the sender of the `MessageB2C` message send to actor C. That means that
>   when C replies, it is not to B, but rather to the temporary actor
>   created by `ask`. In each retry, that will be a new actor, and when the
>   `ask` times out, the temporary actor will be stopped.
>
> Then, when you use `expectNoMessage`, the test will have to wait for the
>   entire duration that you pass to it (100ms) before proceeding. That
>   means that by the time you call `actorC.reply(MessageB2C_Ack())`, the
>   temporary sender of the previous message will have timed out and
>   stopped, and there should be a new retried message in actor C’s
>   mailbox. That’s why the reply goes to dead letters. I believe you will
>   be able to solve this by adding another
>   `actorC.expectMsg(200.milliseconds, MessageB2C())` in between
>   `actorA.expectNoMessage(100.milliseconds)` and
>   `actorC.reply(MessageB2C_Ack())`.
>
> In general, using an `ask` from inside an actor like this is often
>   discouraged in favor of directly modelling the request and response
>   flow directly in the sending actor. This is often simpler and less
>   “magical”, with fewer surprises like this one. This article explains
>   some of the tradeoffs pretty well
>   https://medium.com/@yuriigorbylov/akka-ask-antipattern-8361e9698b20

I found this answer pretty interesting indeed, and I decided to switch my solution adopting the error kernel pattern.